# Surface integrals: why do we use two integrals to find the area of a surface?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Why is it a double sum of rectangles and not a single sum?
Recently I found another way to calculate the area of a surface on my course of differential geometry and really confused me because its one.

$r_u=$ the partial with respect of $u$
$r_v=$ the partial with respect of $v$
and we take the modulus of the cross product

$$\iint |r_u(u,v)\:\times\:r_v(u,v)| \, du \, dv$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to take effext, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.

Comment: just realized its a double integral but still how do you prove this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always think of the double sum as a single sum where you add up all of the rectangles.  But since the rectangles come in rows and columns, it's convenient to think of this as a double sum.  This then naturally leads to the practical method of calculating a double integral as an iterated integral.  (But there's still a theorem to prove to show that this actually works under reasonable conditions, and the pathological counterexamples where it doesn't.)

There are other definitions of the area of a surface involving a sum that is *not* naturally thought of as a double sum.  Instead of dividing the surface into rectangles, divide it into triangles.  Of course, any way of dividing into rectangles gives a triangulation (a way of dividing into triangles), by simply dividing each rectangle in half, but most triangulations won't come this way.  Then you add up the areas of all of the triangles (a single sum) and take the limit as the largest length of any side of any triangle goes to zero.  If you tag your triangulations (by picking a point in each triangle, or without loss of generality by picking a vertex of each triangle), then you can also define more general surface integrals in this way.  (And when relevant, you can orient a triangle by picking a cyclic order of its vertices, define when adjacent triangles have compatible orientations, and thereby do integrals that require a surface to be oriented.)

Comment: thank you sir, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Without introducing a parametrization, you still have two scalar "Lagrangian coordinates" that you need to integrate over in order to do a surface integral, so it's a double integral.

When you introduce a parametrization (as in what you wrote) this is more explicit, since you are associating each point on the curved surface with a point in some flat surface (and you use the magnitude of this cross product to compensate for the change in area scale from your transformation, similar to the Jacobian in "ordinary" change of variables).

Of course, if you want, you can drop the requirement that each variable of integration is scalar, and in this case you might think of a surface integral as a single integral. This point of view makes a lot of sense in the setting of Lebesgue integration.